# Visualising quaternions for key frames in an editor

Tags: models, quaternion, 3d-modeling

I'm working with 3D models from an existing game with its own proprietary file formats, however the way they work is pretty standard:

- Skeleton is defined as a set of bones, each bone either has a parent bone or not (in which case it's the root of the model) and a matrix which moves the bone into the coordinate space of its parent (if I am using the right terminology).
- Skin is defined as a set of vertices and faces.  Each vertex links to 1 or more bones, each with a weighting value that adds up to 1.
- Animation keyframes store values for each bone as translations (x, y, z) and quaternions (x, y, z, w).

I have the source code for the graphics engine, and by combining it with [LearnOpenGL's Skeletal Animation](https://learnopengl.com/Guest-Articles/2020/Skeletal-Animation) (and a lot of trial and error) I was able to render the animation keyframes in wireframes.

What I'm trying to achieve is a visual editor to be able to define my own animation keyframes.  I don't need to edit the skeleton/bone structure, relations or matrices, or edit the skin vertices/faces/weights.

So my question is, how can you do this in a visual way?  **How can you "draw" a quaternion on the screen and let the user move it around with the mouse?** It's just a bunch of numbers - by my understanding the (x, y, z) defines a vector and thereby the plane that is perpendicular to that vector, and the w defines the angle of rotation in that plane.  That's well and good as a mathematical explanation, but nobody can type in numbers for that vector/angle and get the result they want.  They think in terms of "move the leg right a bit" or so on, but that small movement would likely change all 4 values in the quaternion.  How do mainstream 3D editors handle this?

Many thanks!

Comment: "How do mainstream 3D editors handle this" sounds like a question [you could answer with a search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rotation+gizmo&iax=images&ia=images). What do you need us to tell you that you can't get from looking at images or videos of existing tools, or grabbing a free game engine like Unity and trying it its rotation tools yourself?

Comment: Only if I knew what to search for.  I wouldn't have known that 3-axis-thingy is called a "rotation gizmo" to search it.  And it rather demonstrates my point anyway, that's a visualization of roll-pitch-yaw, you grab one of the 3 handles and rotate in one of 3 directions.  Its exactly the system that quaternions are there to avoid.  What if I want to rotate it on a plane tilted 25 degrees left of the red arrow?